# How to fix SyntaxError: Unexpected Token '| |'

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am currently learning JavaScript by setting up audio functions to my Discord bot using node.js and I receive the following error when I execute 'node .' to my Terminal below trying to turn my Discord bot online in my test server:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '||'
at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:360:18)
at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1055:15)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1090:27)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
at load_dir (C:\Users\(myName)\Desktop\DiscordBot\handlers\event_handler.js:8:27)
at C:\Users\(myName)\Desktop\DiscordBot\handlers\event_handler.js:14:38
```

Here is my code related to the error on index.js:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = '-';

const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
client.events = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

client.commands.set(command.name, command);
console.log("registering command", file, command.data?.name);
}

[ 'command_handler', 'event_handler'].forEach(handler =>{
require(`./handlers/${handler}`)(client, Discord);
})

client.on('guildMemberAdd', guildMember =>{
    let welcomeRole = guildMember.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Member')

    guildMember.roles.add(welcomeRole);
    guildMember.guild.channels.cache.get('1016009653131411557').send(`Welcome <@${guildMember.user.id}> to the Velvet Room!`);
});

client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

 const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(" ");
 const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

 if(command === 'ping'){
    client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
 } else if (command == 'twitter'){
     message.channel.send('https://twitter.com/menevraa')
}

if(command === 'clear'){
    client.commands.get('clear').execute(message, args);
} else if (command === 'play') {
    client.commmands.get('play').execute(message, args);
} else if (command === 'leave') {
    client.commands.get('leave').execute(message, args);
}
});

client.login('(key)');
```

And here is the code on event_handler.js as folks have pointed out the error is related to:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = (client, Discord) =>{
    const load_dir = (dir) =>{
        const event_files = fs.readdirSync(`./events/${dir}`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

        for(const file of event_files){
            const event = require(`../events/${dir}/${file}`);
            const event_name = file.split('.')[0];
            client.on(event_name, event.bind(null, Discord, client));
        }
    }

    ['client', 'guild'].forEach(e => load_dir(e));
}
```

The syntaxError did not show before I was setting up additional event and audio functions to my Discord bot, and I have attempted changing the code to:

```
if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
```

with this code instead:

```
if(!content.message.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
```

But it did not fix the error.

Comment: Just curious with this: `client.login('(key)');` What's this? is it string or what? Why there's a `()`

Comment: Feels like your error not in this file, but rather in `\handlers\event_handler.js`. You need to check it instead of this (as I understand) main file.

Comment: @koloml module doesn't nothing to do about the error. Its only the calling if the `token` is invalid.

Comment: couple of things you need to use back ticks on lines that have a variable in them (ie. './handlers/${handler}' should be \`./handlers/${handler}\` and './commands/${file}' should be \`./commands/${file}\`. Honestly its better to use backticks (\`something\`) everywhere you don't have to use " or ' (very few places). Secondly, this looks like a command handler file but the error is relating to an event handler file, line

Comment: @Gh0st Yeah that's my bad, the code you mentioned were originally backticks, but when I tried to paste it into the JS previewer it showed an error and I wasn't sure why.

Answer (score 0):

The || was added in a newer version of node. Try to update node to the latest version and launch your bot again ;)

[Node web page](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)